# Performance difference between Expo and React Native with native code

Tags: react-native

React native is often considered to be better than solutions like Cordova or Ionic because it is true native in the end. But I wonder if it looses this advantage when using Expo XDE or create-react-native-app. Is the performance of react native apps using Expo similar to the ones no using it?

Comment: Curious as well